# Clojure rename loaded libraries

Tags: clojure

Is there any way to rename clojure libraries when you load them with `require` or `use`?

For example, is there any way to do something like

```
(require 'some.include.path.some-library :as something-else)
```

and then reference elements of `some-library` through `something-else/element-name`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at http://clojure.org/libs :

A simple lib with embedded explanations:

```
(ns com.my-company.clojure.examples.my-utils
  (:import java.util.Date)
  (:use [clojure.contrib.def :only (defvar-)])
  (:require [clojure.contrib.shell-out :as shell]))
```

- The **ns** form names the lib's namespace and declares its dependencies. Based on its name, this lib must be contained in a Java resource at the classpath-relative path: com/my_company/clojure/examples/my_utils.clj (note the translations from period to slash and hyphen to underscore).
- The **:import** clause declares this lib's use of java.util.Date and makes it available to code in this lib using its unqualified name.
- The **:use** clause declares a dependency on the clojure.contrib.def lib for its defvar- function only. defvar- may be used in this lib's code using its unqualified name.
- The **:require** clause declares a dependency on the clojure.contrib.shell-out lib and enables using its members using the shorter namespace alias shell.

Comment: Is the crucial difference between `:use` and `:require` here just the aliasing capability of the latter? The documentation for `use` mentions that it's like `require`, but also applies `refer` to the arguments. I have a hard time remembering the differences.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to (require [clojure.contrib :as contrib]) and then reference objects in clojure.contrib as, for example, contrib/def instead of clojure.contrib/def?

Comment: Namespaces do not form a hierarchy. You can do `(require [clojure.contrib.def :as d])` and then access eg. `defvar` as `d/defvar`. `clojure.contrib` has no meaning besides being a symbol if there is no namespace of that name. So what you want is not possible.